# How to make screen capture default to be available via clipboard in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, clipboard

<kbd>⊞ Win</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> turns on the screen capture interface in Win 10 where user can select an area on their screen to be captured and stored to an image. Up until the most recent Win 10 update, the image used to be both available via the clipboard (available via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> on programs that accepts image from clipboard) and available for further editing with the [Snip & Sketch](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/snip-sketch/9mz95kl8mr0) app.

After the recent August update however, screen capped image is no longer available via clipboard for me unless I go through Snip & Sketch first.

Is there a setting that toggles the behavior of <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> which makes the captured image either available via clipboard by default or not?

In any case, is there way to reverse the change and make it available via clipboard by default?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, open Snip and Sketch app > Click on the rightmost button with three vertical dots > settings > toggle Auto copy to clipboard.

Comment: For me, that toggles whether an edited image is sync'd with the clipboard version; not whether it is available via clipboard *without* having to open Snip and Sketch. Btw, when I checked after the Windows update, the setting is checked so it seems the update didn't change that.